# Come resetar formularia apos submit?

Tags: php, javascript, html

já tentei `onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"` porem ele envia um formulário fazio ao email, já tentei

```
echo "<script>alert('Enviado com sucesso!');history.back();</script>"; 
echo ' <script>document.location.reload();</script>';
```

porem o formulário continua preenchido , 
já tentei `document.nome_do_form.reset();` porem ele não acha o formulário para resetar (acredito) o unico que deu foi o onsubmit porem o formulário vazio não adianta de nada

Comment: Samuel, como estás a submeter o formulário? se fôr via AJAX então é melhor fazer aí dentro do `complete`. Se não fôr via AJAX então a página carrega de novo e o formulário vem vazio certo?

Comment: Samuel pode responder à pergunta que escrevi aqui? gostava também de responder mas preciso que responda a essa dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize `document.getElementById` para encontrar o formulario:

```html
<form id="formulario" onsubmit="document.getElementById('formulario').reset();return false">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```